# Sound spatialisation tool. Would this be useful?

Tags: software, panning, doppler, sound-design, sound-effects

Hi, I have recently prototyped a sound spatialisation tool using max/msp as part of a university project. It allows you to load a sound and animate it in a virtual 3d space to add doppler shift, panning, amplitude and high frequency attenuation. It's not quite finished yet but I would grateful if I could get some opinions on the concept, whether it would be useful as a sound design tool, the interface design and workflow.

Here's a link to the .app (Mac only) if anyone wants to try it out:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2579213/Spatial%20Tool.zip

Screenshot:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2579213/1.png

Answer (score 0):

I think the sound file loader is broken (the top row "Mic", "1".. from where you can add them)?

Good start, but I'm positive that you'd need to make it into a VST for it to be useful. The user interface might also be too cumbersome (too many parameters and views), given that the staple is this: http://www.waves.com/Content.aspx?id=244, and the user interface can be as simple as this: http://www.sensomusic.com/wiki/doku.php?id=manual:modules:patches:doppler

Comment: Thankyou for the feedback, that's great. You're right about the sound file loader. It only has one sound "slot" at the minute so the extra tabs that are added do nothing yet. The Waves doppler plugin was a major inspiration for this but I wanted to add 3 dimensional positioning and surround sound panning etc. it's easy to get carried away with ideas instead of focussing on usability.

Comment: @pb How about making the listener position fixed like it's done in every other tool? It already simplifies a lot, because then you'd be only focusing on moving the sound sources. Here's another example of a "3D panner": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pm3ZRSLMWQA

Comment: Imho, I don't feel that Waves Doppler is a great example - it's so cumbersome and constrained that I cn't stand it with a passion. Makes me avoid doing doppler unless I absolutely must, and even then I sort of groan. The GRM Doppler though has a much more intuitive and fluid interface

Answer (score 0):

Dude, that is so dope. Try to make it more of a visualization tool more than anything else and you might even make some sales (unless you're planning to release it for free, which would be cool!)

Refer to the visualizations on Windows Media Player and Foobar. Wavecandy in fruity loops does pretty much the same thing but, hey, if you make yours totally original and make it look good people would use it ;)

edit: didnt read the part where you mentioned modifying the sound. I'm stoked for this and will be following this thread.