# Can anyone think of any interesting ways of using Iannix?

Tags: control

If you're not familiar with Iannix have a look [here](http://www.iannix.org/en/presentation.php).

Has anybody done anything cool with this? I've had a bit of a play around with the examples in Max and think there's great potential for some interesting sound design applications, but I cant quite put my finger on *the* best use for it.

I'm thinking along the lines of object based automated surround panning or some other spatial control or complex control of lots of parameters (of something!).

Thoughts ???

EDIT:

For anyone interested, here's an HRTF panning example which uses Iannix to control the position of three audio objects. When you're listening, think of the circle as being left, right, in-front and behind. You also need to listen on headphones for the effect to work.

[youtube]by5S3g2BjAY[/youtube]

I'm hoping to put together a more complex solution asap, hopefully with elevation and 3d positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Doppler.

Surround panning.

WYSIWYG reverb or binauralization.

Vocal synthesis and processing (control e.g. formants and pitch. Think Kyma and the Wii controller as a reference.).

Various live performance audio effects.

...

Note: none of this is particularly new, but ofc one could manage to figure out something special.

Comment: Yes, pretty much what I was thinking. I'm still quite excited about the spatial processing possibilities though, I just found some interesting 3d examples so perhaps 3d hrtf spatialisation could work.

Comment: @Mark Well, it probably works, but to reach for a practical solution (you're already limited by the Max framework) can be a hurdle. Many good, although commercial solutions exist as well as more open audio patchers (while they may not have something that Iannix adds out-of-the-box).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what sort of sound designer/sound artist you are but I feel like Iannix is suited to high art applications where the extra difficulty of programming it (added to the extra difficulty of Max when compared to more commercial software) and the extra layers of complexity involved are traded off for more abstract possibilities and more potential real-time control.  In other words, I would be really interested to delve into something like this if I were working on an art installation, similar to the occasions in which I would already use Max.  I don't know that I would be able to efficiently implement it for more common sound design tasks.  Either way you have to be self-directed with it and push the envelope.

On a side note, I wonder if there is any possible integration with something like the Max patch that this guy posted on this forum a while back:
[Sound spatialisation tool. Would this be useful?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/19095/sound-spatialisation-tool-would-this-be-useful)

I haven't tried out the patch but I was intrigued by it because I've been considering the possible merit of something like that for theater sound design, where you often have unconventional arrays of speakers but need to spatialize things precisely.  Wouldn't it be cool to have a customizable Max patch for that situation?

Just throwing out some thoughts here.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts... I'm not really sure what sort of sound designer I am, but like to think I've got one foot in the more conventional post-production world and another in the art/academic side of things - hence my interest in the possibilities of combining the two. As for the spatialisation patch you link to, I've just successfully done some panning using Iannix and another HRTF patch which is very similar, seems to work well so far. The theatre array is also in interesting idea, I've built a 4,0 surround patch which could be easily adapted to more speakers, so get in touch if you...

Comment: ...have any particular features in mind, we might be able to make that happen easily. 